# Change dynamically the field bound to a TextBox into an ASP.Net GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I populate with List<>.
GridView's columns are TextBoxes (as TemplateField).
The list might contain objects from 2 different custom classes whose fields to display are not exactly the same.

For class1, I need to display in GridView:

class1.Name

class1.field1

For class2, I need to display in GridView:

class2.Name

class2.field2

So I can setup the gridview into the aspx so that it displays the class1 items:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="DG_Table" runat="server" style="z-index: 1;
                    autogeneratecolumns="False" 
            onrowcommand="DG_Table_RowCommand"  
            <Columns>


 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="field1" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="field1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("field1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>

 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Displaying a `List<Class1>` into the DataGrid works fine.
Now, if I want to display items of class2 into the datagrid, I will do something like:

```
DG_Table.DataSource = new List<Class2>;
DG_Table.DataBind();
```

This will obviously cause this kind of error :
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'Class2' does not contain a property with the name 'Field1'.

So I suppose that, before binding to the List, I need to convert my second column into the code behind.
What would be the equivalent of

```
Text='<%# Bind("field1") %>'
```

into the code behind?

I expected something like this :

```
((TextBox)DG_Table.Columns[2]).Text = "";
```

But this conversion is not allowed.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `anonymous` type to bind the data just before the binding the data convert them to the `anonymous` types and then bind them.

Change your grid view as,

```
<asp:GridView ID="DG_Table" runat="server" style="z-index: 1;autogeneratecolumns="False" onrowcommand="DG_Table_RowCommand">  
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="field1" >
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="field1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FieldValue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

For binding your first class,

```
gridView1.DataSource = class1List.Select(x=> new{Name = x.Name,FieldValue = x.Field1});
gridview1.DataBind();
```

When binding the second class list

```
gridView1.DataSource = class2List.Select(x=> new{Name = x.Name,FieldValue = x.Field1});
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you very much for your fast assistance :-).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the second TextBox it Binds or Evals "field1" which is not a property in Class2.

You can do as same as it was mentioned in the @code of code answer or just Change the Create a Model class for the View to bind it

```
Class GvItemModel 
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Field{get; set;}
}
```

And past it always as dataSource

```
var dataSource = new List<CvItemModel>();
... //Load class1 or Class2 it depends on your choice
```

Then

```
DG_Table.DataSource = dataSource ;
DG_Table.DataBind();
```

Change your second TextBox dataSource.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="field1" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="field1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Field") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: He know's that he is asking for solution. It is more a comment than answer.

Comment: @CoderofCode is it ok now ? :-)